# Using Case statements in Filter in Looker Views

Tags: sql, filter, view, looker

I am adding CASE statements to my filter in my views. I basically want that if the user types `Harry` the filtering should happen on `Gryffindor`. This is my code:

```
filter: house {
    # type: string
    # sql: ${TABLE}.house ;;
    sql:  CASE
            WHEN ${TABLE}.house LIKE '%harry%' THEN ${TABLE}.house = 'gryffindor'
            WHEN ${TABLE}.house LIKE '%luna%' THEN ${TABLE}.house = 'ravenclaw'
            WHEN ${TABLE}.house LIKE '%ernie%' THEN ${TABLE}.house = 'hufflepuff'
            WHEN ${TABLE}.house LIKE '%draco%' THEN ${TABLE}.house = 'slytherin'
          ELSE ${TABLE}.house = ${TABLE}.house END ;;
  }
```

When I go to explore and type out `harry` in my filter, it is returning all the values like:

```
gryffindor
ravenclaw
hufflepuff
slytherin
other
```

This is what my SQL code is looking like:

```
SELECT
    "house" AS "hogwarts.house"
FROM
    "schools"."hogwarts" AS "hogwarts"
WHERE (CASE
            WHEN hogwarts.house LIKE '%harry%' THEN hogwarts.house = 'gryffindor'
            WHEN hogwarts.house LIKE '%luna%' THEN hogwarts.house = 'ravenclaw'
            WHEN hogwarts.house LIKE '%ernie%' THEN hogwarts.house = 'hufflepuff'
            WHEN hogwarts.house LIKE '%draco%' THEN hogwarts.house = 'slytherin'
            ELSE hogwarts.house = hogwarts.house END )
GROUP BY
    1
ORDER BY
    1
LIMIT 500
```

This query will obviously return all the values.

Is there a way that in the filter if I enter `harry` it only return:

```
gryffindor
```

Comment: I would be surprised if that query returns all values... Skip the `case` expression in the WHERE clause, use basic `AND`/`OR` constructions instead.

Comment: @jarlh, the point is if the user puts in a value like harry the query in the `where` statement should be `WHERE hogwarts.house = 'gryffindor'`. Is that possible?

Comment: How do you know Harry lives in gryffindor? That type of information should be stored in another table, perhaps called students.